# Errors when using a struct in class

Tags: c++, class, struct

I'm in C++, IDE is Visual Studio 2012. I have no idea why I can't do this, it makes no sense at all. I'm trying to put a struct inside of a class, as title says, but it simply will not let me do it. I've tried putting it in public, private, protected, and then tried putting it in global scope, and nothing works.

```
class foobar
{
public:
    struct foo
    {
        int ass;
    };

    foo bar;
    bar.ass = 1; //getting a weird error on this line
};
```

How would I put a struct in a class? Thanks for helping

Comment: What is the "weird error"?

Comment: There is always a reason; in this case, it's that _you_ did something wrong. Attitude adjustment required.

Comment: Could it be, that your assignment statement isn't in a function or method?

Answer (score 9):

If what you are trying to do is to have the `ass` member initialized to `1` when constructing objects of type `foo`, then **in C++11** you can do that this way:

```
class foobar
{
public:

    struct foo
    {
        int ass = 1;
    //          ^^^
    };

    foo bar;
};
```

You can see a [live example here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3ji7qM$2).

The above syntax is equivalent to the more verbose constructor-based initialization, which is the *only option* **in C++03** (and possibly also in the version of the VC11 compiler that comes with VS2012, which is known for [not being fully compliant with the C++11 Standard](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx)):

```
class foobar
{
public:

    struct foo
    {
        foo() : ass(1) { }
    //        ^^^^^^^^

        int ass;
    };

    foo bar;
};
```

Answer (score 5):

C++ does not allow initializing variables inside the class declaration. You *must* write a constructor to do this.

Comment: Ha, well thanks. I didn't know that you just couldn't make it in the scope of the class, I don't know why the designer of C++ made it that way, but thanks for telling me.

Comment: Several reasons, all of which make sense, and are out of the scope of this comment thread. Funny story: language designers are cleverer than you.

Comment: @JBentley Yeah I guess that's why the language never really took off, huh? Can't wait to use yours, by the way.

Comment: @Lightness I fail at sarcasm, apparently :)